# JDBC password encryption in SQL Anywhere 16

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc, connection-string, sqlanywhere

anyone know a nice solution to encrypt the password in ConnectionString?

When i'll go the normal way with sybase/sap tools i can connect 
with `dbisql.exe @encrypted_config_file.cfg`

in encrypted_config_file.cfg informations about servername, user and password stored. Then i can encyrpt this file with dbhide.exe.
now only the database server can connect without telling the user the real password.

anyone now a solution like this in java or C, but in connection string as an option or an parameter

```
--using jconn3.jar 
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName( "com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" ).newInstance() ); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:HOSTNAME:PORT?ServiceName=Servername", "USER", "PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Sybase info-center site](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1500/html/newfesd/newfesd95.htm), It seems you need to do something like the following:

```
String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:myserver:3697";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("ENCRYPT_PASSWORD ", “true”);
props.put("JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS",
"org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider");

/* Set up additional connnection properties as needed */
props.put("user", "xyz");
props.put("password", "123");

/* get  the connection */
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Hopefully this will be helpful.

Comment: It seems to be that this code is for "transport" an encrypted password from client to server.

Comment: i'm searching for an external solution like .properties, but encrypted.
in the java code above anyone with a littlebit knowlege can "extract" the jar archive and decrypt or just read the plaintext password can login in to database.

Comment: Yes, It seems you need to do something like creating a binary file in Java, then you need to create a new Java class (let's say DataSourceInfo) that encrypt the Plain text and store it in binary file.

After that (When you are initializing the connection), you need to get the necessary information such as username/password by using the DataSourceInfo class